# InvalidArgumentException: Code does not exist in .../vendor/magento/module-google-optimizer/Observer/AbstractSave.php:158

Tags: magento2, error, magento-2.1.3

This error only shows up once in my exception log and I haven't been able to reproduce it. All I have is the code stack

> InvalidArgumentException: Code does not exist in .../vendor/magento/module-google-optimizer/Observer/AbstractSave.php:158

This is a new error to me and I'm not sure how to fix this. Does anyone have any ideas?

UPDATE: Here is the code stack from the exception log and I'm using Magento 2.1.3 with no extensions at this time

```
[2017-01-18 19:44:26] main.CRITICAL: InvalidArgumentException: Code does not exist in vendor/magento/module-google-optimizer/Observer/AbstractSave.php:158
Stack trace:
#0 vendor/magento/module-google-optimizer/Observer/AbstractSave.php(97): Magento\GoogleOptimizer\Observer\AbstractSave->_loadCode()
#1 vendor/magento/module-google-optimizer/Observer/AbstractSave.php(61): Magento\GoogleOptimizer\Observer\AbstractSave->_processCode()
#2 vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(73): Magento\GoogleOptimizer\Observer\AbstractSave->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#3 vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(61): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\GoogleOptimizer\Observer\Product\SaveGoogleExperimentScriptObserver), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#4 vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#5 var/generation/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('catalog_product...', Array)
#6 vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(802): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('catalog_product...', Array)
#7 vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php(921): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->afterSave()
#8 vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Observer/AfterEntitySave.php(34): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product->afterSave()
#9 vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(73): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Observer\AfterEntitySave->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#10 vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(61): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Observer\AfterEntitySave), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#11 vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#12 var/generation/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('magento_catalog...', Array)
#13 vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EventManager.php(51): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('magento_catalog...', Array)
#14 vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Update.php(108): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EventManager->dispatchEntityEvent('Magento\\Catalog...', 'save_after', Array)
#15 vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EntityManager.php(87): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Update->execute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Array)
#16 vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product.php(695): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#17 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#18 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->___callParent('save', Array)
#19 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'save', Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Array, 'apply_catalog_r...')
#20 vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Plugin/Indexer/Product/Save/ApplyRules.php(40): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#21 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\CatalogRule\Plugin\Indexer\Product\Save\ApplyRules->aroundSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#22 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'save', Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Array, 'catalogsearchFu...')
#23 vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Plugin/Product.php(51): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#24 vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Plugin/Product.php(24): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Product->addCommitCallback(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#25 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Product->aroundSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#26 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'save', Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Array, 'clean_cache')
#27 vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/FlushCacheByTags.php(71): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#28 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\FlushCacheByTags->aroundSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#29 var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->___callPlugins('save', Array, Array)
#30 vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(631): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#31 vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save.php(110): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save()
#32 vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save->execute()
#33 vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#36 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#37 vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#38 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#39 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#40 vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#41 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#42 var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#43 vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#44 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#45 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#46 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#47 vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#48 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#49 var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#50 vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#51 vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#52 index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#53 {main} [] []
```

Comment: Please don't just dump error messages in the question form. You should at least explain
when it happens and if you did any changes before. To debug errors, follow this guide:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Comment: I added more info but I can't reproduce it

Comment: "All I have is the code stack" Could you add the stack trace? This is quite important. Also what M2 exact version are you running? What extensions did you add? Do you use a custom theme? Did it work before? What did you do just before this error came up? You should always add all info you have...

Comment: @7ochem  I added what information I have and I apologize about not including it earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that you have to disable content experiments by going to Sales > Google API